# How to enable Disqus comments in a Wordpress theme I'm creating from scratch?

Tags: theme-development, comments, disqus

I've installed the Disqus comments plugin, and I see that it works fine with 'off-the-shelf' themes. However, I'm creating my very own custom theme, and Disqus doesn't show up at all in my theme. Maybe that's because I've not done anything to enable comments in my theme, such as adding comments theme support in my functions.php file, or comments-specific code in my index.php or single.php files.  I (naively) assumed the Disqus plugin would handle everything.

Perhaps if I learn how to code my theme to support basic comments, the Disqus plugin would then work.  I haven't tried that yet because I'm worried it might be a 'wild goose chase'.  I'd greatly appreciate if anyone could push me in the right direction with some advice on how to 'attack' this issue.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Disqus replaces the [`comments_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comments_template/) function, which is normally responsible for outputting comments into a template. So as long as your single template uses `comments_template()` for displaying comments, Disqus should be able to take over that section of the template and handle comments itself.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to use comments_template() in single.php, but Disqus is still not overriding it somehow.  I uploaded my code here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/285693/comments-template-not-being-overriden-by-disqus-plugin

Comment: Under Disqus settings, changing the 'External Java Script Files' and 'Template Conflicts' checkboxes seems to have worked.  I haven't had time to figure out why it worked.

Comment: Are you using `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` in your theme? Scripts won't load if you don't, and as far as I can tell that setting tells it not to properly enqueue a script the WordPress way and just load it on the page. Enqueueing scripts requires `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()`.

Comment: wp_footer worked.  This is the solution that was missing.